# regex can't recognize "\n"?

Tags: c#, regex

so at the end the end(after few days of debuging) i found a problem. It isnt in regex at all :/  . It seams that i was trimming ekstra white spaces with

```
intput= Regex.Replace(input, "\\s+", " ");
```

so all new lines are replaced with " ". Stupid! Moderator, please remove this if unnecesary!

I have regexp for tokenizing some text and it looks like this :

```
"(?<html>Ç)|
(?<number>\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?(?=[][ \f\n\r\t\v!?.,():;\"'„Ç]|$))|
(?<other>(?:[^][Ç \f\n\r\t\v!?.,():;\"'„A-Za-zčćšđžČĆŠĐŽäöÖü][^ Ç\f\n\r\t\vA-Za-zčćšđžČĆŠĐŽäöÖü]*)?[^][ Ç\f\n\r\t\v!?.,():;\"'„A-Za-zčćšđžČĆŠĐŽäöÖü](?=[][!?.,():;\"'„]*(?:$|[ Ç\f\n\r\t\v])))|
(?<word>(?:[^][ Ç\f\n\r\t\v!?.,():;\"'„][^ Ç\f\n\r\t\v]*)?[^][ Ç\f\n\r\t\v!?.,():;\"'„])|
(?<punctuation>[][ \f\n\r\t\v!?.,():;\"'„])"
```

Problem is in this part: `(?<punctuation>[][ \f\n\r\t\v!?.,():;\"'„])`.  So when im prsing text with input `"\n\n"` it is grouping in punctuation matches: `" "," "` - in other words, space and space... and I don't know why?

Comment: isn't your regex working at line level, as e.g. in perl?

Comment: I'm sorry... this isn't very clear... it turns newlines into spaces? Do you want it to group punctuation marks? And while I'm at it, what is this `[]` you keep writing?

Comment: does this also happen with the RegexOptions.Multiline option turned on and off?

Comment: [^]] and []] is correct! I read about how to include ] literal in [ ] and it says that "]" must be first literal in [ ] literal group. (after not if included ^)

Answer (score 5):

I could be wrong, but you need to hand the String as String to the RegEx...means you need to escape the backslashes.

```
... (?=[][ \\f\\n\\r\\t\\v!?.,():;\\" ...
```

Or otherwise C# will replace \n with a linebreak within the RegEx-Statement.

**Edit:** It's also [possible to use literal strings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html), but the need to be marked with  beginning @ (see Martin's answer).

Comment: Or just use verbatim string literals: `@"..."`

Comment: Could a literal string not be used here?  e.g. var regex = @"<regex>"

Comment: You three are right, it's also possible to use literal strings...I've edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you put an `@` in front of string you can use single backslashes and line-breaks will be recognized.

```
 @"(?<html>Ç)|
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhiteSpace`

Update:

Are you sure `[^]` is correct? Unless it's somekind of character group (that I have never used), that will be the same as `.` . Same goes for `[]`.  Perhaps I just have not used all of RE before :p

Comment: [^]] and []] is correct!  I read about how to include ] literal in [ ]  and it says that "]" must be first literal in [ ] literal group. (after not if included ^)

Comment: RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace  didnt help :/ 

so i cant find where i read about it but if you want to include symbol "]"  in list of literals [abc] , u must put it on first place (i couldn escape that literal). so [ab]c]] is wrong  [ab\\]c] is wrong too. Right way is to put "]" at first place after start of literal group []abc]  [^]abc] (if its a nogation). This works fine by me.  So in []abc]  literals are ] a b c .